# Hyperledger Fabric: Is there any way to change settings of fabric-ca-server after it has been started?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I started an instance of fabric-ca-server but misspelled the name of `--ca.chainfile` while starting it. It did not give an error on start but when I made requests to the server, the requests failed and that's how I learned that I had misspelled the name of the file. Is there any way for me to correct the `--ca.chainfile` setting without having to restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make changes, as in all the fabric elements, by environment variables. You can see it here:

https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientconfig.html?highlight=environment

Don't know which specific one is the one that you need, try with: FABRIC_CA_CHAINFILE or FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CHAINFILE